# Add logo in very bottom right corner

Tags: latex

I have been trying to insert a (transparent) logo in the bottom right corner in the background of my title page without affecting the text in Overleaf. Unfortunately, I haven't found a similar use case and have tried many different options for quite some time, but it doesn't work the way I need it to. Can someone please help me in this regard?

I would like it to look like this. As you can see, there is a logo inserted in the lower right corner.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an image to the page background via the `shipout/background` hook. To make positioning easier, I'm using tikz in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,opacity=0.5]
  \node[anchor=south east] at ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-3cm]current page.south east) {
    \includegraphics[width=16cm]{example-image-duck}
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a tiny remark. In case this doesn't work, OP should make sure the latest LaTeX distribution is installed, I think it must be at least from 2020.

Comment: @Celdor In the question they mention overleaf, which has TL2022 available. Should be new enough